# how we can insert the data from one table to another table with foreign key in laravel?

Tags: php, css, laravel, eloquent

suppose I have one table("attachment") and another one is table("Brand").
I want to attach a brand_logo from brand table which will save into table("attachment"). I am beginner sorry in advance.
please help me.\
This is my Brand controller.......

```
 public function create()
{
    $brands = Brand::all();
    $catagories = Catagory::all();
    $attachments = Attachment::all();
    return view('system-mgmt/brand/create', ['brands' => $brands, 'catagories' => $catagories,'attachments'=>  $attachments]);

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Catagory::findOrFail($request['catID']);
    Attachment::findOrFail($request['attachmentID']);
    $this->validateInput($request);
     Brand::create([
        'brandsName' => $request['brandsName'],
        'attachmentID' => $request['attachmentID'],
        'catID' => $request['catID']
    ]);

    return redirect()->intended('system-management/brand');
}
```

Here is my html code,this code is getting data from attachment table...but my requirement is" data will insert by user"

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Brand Logo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select class="form-control" name="attachmentID">
                                @foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
                                    <option value="{{$attachment->id}}">{{$attachment->attachmentName}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can you add the code to help

Comment: You need to go through the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Create the entries for brand, get the ID of the row, use that to create the entry for attachment.

Comment: how?? please  with example

Answer (score 1):

You want to insert data one table to another **relational** table is not a best practice.
Here you can use [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) query when you select data and avoid insert process it's better. 
 
Join `brands` table with `attachments` table and access `brand_logo` following `foreign key`.

```
//Please make sure your table and field name is correct   
$attachments = DB::table('attachments')
                ->leftJoin('brands', 'attachments.id', '=', 'brands.attachmentID')
                ->select('attachments.*','brands.brand_logo')
                ->first();

echo $attachments->brand_logo;
```

> However some time need to copy on table data to others table in this purpose you can do this.

```
//Laravel DB raw insert query
\DB::insert("INSERT INTO table_a(fld_a,fld_b)
    SELECT
        fld_a,fld_b // Make sure select column same sequence of insert field name(fld_a,fld_b).
    FROM
        table_b
    WHERE table_b.id > 100  //condition
        ");
```

Details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: 'attachmentID' => $request['attachmentID'], i want to insert data(''brandlogo') through foreign key ???

Comment: Hi, @NasirSubhan I updated my answer following your comment. Maybe it's help you to solve your issue. Thanks